# Creating textarea with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a textarea in a specific place near my buttons. Heres the current code:

```
var test = $('.content-dialog').dialog({
  width: '98%',
  height: $(window).height() - 20,
  position: ['top', 10],
  resizable: true,
  resize: function(evt, ui) {
    CKEDITOR.instances['content[content]'].resize(
      $(this).width() - 5,
      $(this).height() - 10
    );
  },
  close: function(){
    $('span[id="cke_content[content]"]').remove();
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Save',
      'class': 'green',
      id: 'content_save',
      click: function(){
        log_dlg.dialog('open');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      click: function() {
        $('.content-dialog').dialog('close');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

How can i create a textarea field or just a textfield in the same container where the buttons are created?

Comment: use call back of function and append textarea there

Comment: I see your request in last line, why you need a text area in the same container? Can't be a descent of you container?

Comment: The buttons are located on the bottom of the container, i just want to add a textarea at the bottom too

Answer (score -1):

As far I see used **dialog**, I always used as "decoraror" of an existing html.

so decorating following code as dialog you've a form with text area as dialog:

```
<div class='content-dialog' style='display: none'>
<form action='index.php' method="GET">
your text area
<textarea>
some text
</textarea>
</form>
</div>
```

**ADD on commment**

As you can see in [enter link description here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#theming) the button container is:

> .ui-dialog-buttonpane

so (**see the trick line**) (the code is untested):

```
<!-- dialog hook -->
<div class='content-dialog' style='display: none'>
</div>


<!-- textarea code -->
<div id='textareacode' style='display: none'>
<form action='index.php' method="GET">
your text area
<textarea>
some text
</textarea>
</form>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var test = $('.content-dialog').dialog({
  width: '98%',
  height: $(window).height() - 20,
  position: ['top', 10],
  resizable: true,
  resize: function(evt, ui) {
    CKEDITOR.instances['content[content]'].resize(
      $(this).width() - 5,
      $(this).height() - 10
    );
  },
  close: function(){
    $('span[id="cke_content[content]"]').remove();
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Save',
      'class': 'green',
      id: 'content_save',
      click: function(){
        log_dlg.dialog('open');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      click: function() {
        $('.content-dialog').dialog('close');
      }
    }
  ]
});

// here the trick
$('.content-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane').append($('#textareacode').text())

</script>
```